# Парсинг строки с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, строки

Помогите вытащить данные из строки с помощью регулярного выражения.
Ко мне приходит строка:
`<td class="news_date">21 мар 2022        </td><td><a href="https://www.bills.ru/news/?  bid=598344">Минстрой не планирует вводить мораторий на начисление пеней и долгов по ЖКУ</a>                        <span class="bizon_api_news_original_date">(от 21 мар 2022)</span></td></tr><tr class="'`

1. С помощью выражения `preg_match('/[0-9]{1,2}\s[а-я].+?/iU'`, $item, $arr) я получаю
   `'21 мар 2022        </td>'`
2. Далее с помощью инструкции `preg_replace("/^\s*|\s*$/", '', str_replace('</td>', '', $arr))` привожу строку в состояние "21 мар 2022"

Вопрос:
Как с помощью первого регулярного выражении (в п. 1) все почистить, функция trim не работает почему то.

Comment: Почитайте как работают группы. С помощью них вы можете сразу же извлечь все нужные данные без лишнего мусора

Comment: Тут можно по идее и без группы обойтись, просто вместо .+? сделать шаблон года, например: `[0-9]{1,2}\s[а-я]+\s\d{4}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с одним `preg_replace()`. Удаляем все символы с начала строки до первой цифры ИЛИ все символы после первого вхождения 4-х цифр до конца строки ИЛИ все подряд идущие пробельные символы, кроме первого

```
<?php 
$array = [
    '<td class="news_date">21 мар 2022        </td><td><a href="https://www.bills.ru/news/?  bid=598344">Минстрой не планирует вводить мораторий на начисление пеней и долгов по ЖКУ</a>                        <span class="bizon_api_news_original_date">(от 21 мар 2022)</span></td></tr><tr class="',
    '<td class="news_date">  25   апреля   2023        </td><td><a href="https://www.bills.ru/news/?  bid=598344">Минстрой не планирует вводить мораторий на начисление пеней и долгов по ЖКУ</a>                        <span class="bizon_api_news_original_date">(от 21 мар 2022)</span></td></tr><tr class="'
    ];
$res = preg_replace('/^[^\d]*|(?<=\d{4}).*$|(?<=\s)\s+/', "", $array);
var_dump($res);
?>
```

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "21 мар 2022"
  [1]=>
  string(20) "25 апреля 2023"
}
```